# Get a real/parent url from included php file

Tags: javascript, php, url

I have an external php file included in my header. I need the url of the website it's on in a variable. `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` doesn't work because it gives me the url of the included php file.

I tried:

```
$currentPage = "<script>document.write(document.URL);</script>";
```

Which, when echoed, gives me the correct url, but for reasons unbeknownst to me, doesn't give me the actual url when trying to see what's inside of the url, ie:

url is `www.website.com/front.php`,

```
if (strpos($currentPage,"front")) { echo "true"; }else { echo "false"; }
```

will echo `false`

How can I get the real url of the webpage and programmatically check it for a specific string, from within an external included php file?

Comment: Before you solve your question, I think it is imperative that you understand why the $currentPage variable does not hold the document.URL.

Comment: Perhaps the best way to understand what is happening is to replace "front" with "document.URL" in your `strpos()` if condition.

Comment: Are you trying to tell me that what I'm comparing "front" to is the string "<script>document.write(document.URL);</script>"?

Comment: Yes. The execution of JavaScript does not enter the picture until the PHP has finished executing and the web server has sent the response to the client.

Comment: I figured that out a long time ago. It doesn't really help me find a solution. The best one I've found is to redirect the current page (or submit a form) with a get value in the url, then use that value in PHP, but I really can't redirect.

Comment: I don't believe that `$_SERVER['REQUST_URI']` would return the path to an included file rather than the requested file.

Comment: Apparently it does if the included file is external.

Comment: What does "external" mean?

Comment: It's on a different server, at a different url.

Comment: I would advise against designing your system to include PHP files from other servers. I think that would expose you to many security and deployment issues. However, in the academic interest of solving the immediate issue, I would pass the including file's request url to the included script via the querystring: ex., include('{remote_url}?request_url=' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);

Comment: Yeah, we don't store any info that needs to be secured. We probably wouldn't be doing it, except that the first server is bigcommerce (html/js, php is not allowed). The include code is part of their API. I already tried: <script> url = document.URL;var a = url.indexOf("cart"); if (a > 0) { popup = "true"; }

document.write("%%Include.http://www.website.com/toolbox/fetch/toolbox.php?store_id=123&amp;popup=" + popup + "%%");

However, only the first get value registers for some reason when writing it with js. Thank you for trying, I'm not sure there is a solution.